# Динамическое редактирование свойств кнопки в android приложении

Tags: android, xml, вёрстка, shape

В своей программе я динамически создаю круглые кнопки:

```
for (i = 0; i < k; i ++) {
    xPosition = 50;
    for (j = 0; j < k; j ++) {
        roundButton = (Button) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.button, null);
        roundButton.setId(i);

        roundButton.setX(xPosition);
        roundButton.setY(yPosition);

        roundButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape);

        xPosition += step;


        roundButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        llMain.addView(roundButton);
    }
    yPosition += step;
}
```

Сама кнопка описана в **button.xml**

```
android:background="@drawable/shape"
```

Как видно, свойство `background` ссылается на **shape.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadius="20dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="1dp"
    android:useLevel="false">
    <solid
        android:color="#cccaca">
    </solid>
</shape>
```

Мне необходимо динамически изменять свойство `innerRadius`, описанное в **shape.xml**.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В английской версии сайта в ответе на подобный вопрос говорится, что innerRadius может быть определен только через xml-файл:
[См. здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346112/creating-ring-shape-in-android-code)

Answer (score 2):

Изображение полученное с помощью `shape.xml` называется `GradientDrawable`.

То есть вам надо сделать каст вашей кнопки на `GradientDrawable` и применить метод `setInnerRadius ()`.

Документация [здесь](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html)

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать менять Background кнопки
Допустим так:

```
roundButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            roundButton.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.shape1));
        }
    });
```

Если мало состояний то вполне сойдет

Comment: мне как раз нужен вариант, в котором изменяется не файл, а свойство

Answer (score 0):

Программно менять углы можно так:

```
StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();

// цвета кнопки в НЕнажатом состоянии
int[] colors_normal = {Color.parseColor(start_gradient), Color.parseColor(end_gradient)};
GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, colors_normal);
gd.setCornerRadius(radius_value); // радиус углов кнопки

// состояния
states.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}, *some_state*); // кнопка нажата
states.addState(new int[]{}, gd); // кнопка НЕ нажата

// фон
btn_unlock.setBackground(states);
```

Comment: Тем не менее, как поменять свойство именно `android:innerRadius="20dp"`? Весь втопрос, как мне кажется, именно в этом.